# API Manager store. Multiple API Keys

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

How can I configure WSO2 API Manager to handle [Multiple Authentication API Keys](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/api-keys/) in the store's API Console? I would like it show fields: Authentication and clientId, for example. But it only shows the field for Authentication despite of I built my swagger file with both headers in .

I do handle this Auth headers in my application backend. And I am testing my swagger file in the swagger-editor and works fine ([Swagger Editor asking for two API Keys Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnHuj.jpg)).

Answer (score 0):

Swagger can handle a lot itself, it's only a definition file. It doesn't mean a (any) product must support all options.

WSO2AM reads only the authorization header (`Authorization` by default, can be changed). The header is cleared before sending to the backend.

If you want to be able sending a custom header to the backend from the API Store, you can define a header parameter (not as an api key)

WSO2AM can be configured to send a JWT token to the backend with client information, that's how backend can get and validate the identity information.